# Angular 'this' doesn't assign value

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have the following code, and the problem is, that value fetched from json is not assigned to the vm variable

```
    (function() {

    angular
      .module('app', [])
      .controller('theController', theController);

    function theController($http) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.message = [];
    vm.message2 = [];

    fetchJSON();
    console.log(vm.message);
    vm.message2 = vm.message;

    function fetchJSON() {
      $http
        .get('http://beta.json-generator.com/api/json/get/4y2l2jq8l')
        .success(function(data) {
          vm.message = data;
        });
    }
  }
})();
```

The value I assign to vm.message in fetchJson method doesn't appear in the main view, so when I set message2 = message it is still empty.

Live demo: http://codepen.io/matt23/pen/PZbNQa?editors=101

Comment: `$http` is async, which means it allows your other code to continue to run and your `.success()` is run at a later time.  Your `console.log` and assignment calls are happening immediately, before the `.success()` has happened.

Comment: You are right! I've been spending whole day on solving that issue, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the vm.message2 inside the fetchJSON function?

You are setting the vm.message2 right after fetchSON() hence the success message has not yet bene defined.

```html
function fetchJSON() {
      $http
        .get('http://beta.json-generator.com/api/json/get/4y2l2jq8l')
        .success(function(data) {
          vm.message = data;
          // HERE
        });
    }
```

or you can add another callback:

```html
.complete(function() {

});
```

Comment: `.complete` is not a method of AngularJS `$http.get()` and `.success` is deprecated. See the Docs -- https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#deprecation-notice